# Antd Popover close on click inside popover

Tags: javascript, popover, antd

Here is a [sandbox Antd popover](https://codesandbox.io/embed/popover-minimal-reproduction-cmfy8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

Popover by default closes whenever you click anywhere outside of the popover window. I want to also have the popover close whenever you click on any content inside the popover

I have seen some examples where popover is called and rendered in a class like [this](https://codesandbox.io/embed/pmrq7q22q0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark). Where they use state to control visibility and in content they can use onClick={this.hide} to close the window whenever you click on that content.

I would like to keep popover in a function and Links as its own function that just returns a list of links.

For example, I have tried using react useState and onBlur to achieve my desired result like [this](https://codesandbox.io/embed/popover-reproduction-8o5gq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark). In that sandbox if you look at the console log, the link in Links is never clicked.

Is this possible with antd popover?

***edit:*** I would prefer a solution that does not pass anything from the function with popover to the function producing links.

Answer (score 0):

Try sharing the `visible` state with `Link` component:

```
function Links({ setShow }) {
  return (
    <div
      onClick={e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setShow(false);
      }}
      onBlur={() => {
        setShow(false);
      }}
    >
      <a href="j">Then click here</a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit popover reproduction]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Something like this has crossed my mind. But in my project, Links is called first and then passed into the popover function, right now anyway. So I would prefer a solution that does not pass anything from the function with popover to the function with links in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me. OnMaskClick="MaskClick"

```
   public void  MaskClick()
{
       PopoverVisible = false;
}
```